# Accumulation points of the set $S=\{(\frac {1} {n}, \frac {1} {m}) \space m, n \in \mathbb N\}$

Tags: general-topology, analysis

The exercise is to find the accumulation points of the set  $S=\{(\frac {1} {n}, \frac {1} {m}) \space m, n \in \mathbb N\}$

I'm trying to prove that if $A$={accumulation points of the set $S$}, then $A=\{(0,0), (\frac {1} {n},0),(0,\frac {1} {m}) \space n,m \in \mathbb N\}$. I could prove that the set of the right side of the equality is included in $A$. I don't know how to prove the other inclusion, which means that if $x$ is an accumulation point of $S$, then $x$ has to be $(0,0)$, or of the form $(\frac {1} {n},0)$ or $(0,\frac {1} {m})$.

Answer (score 2):

Find the distance between points $\left(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{m}\right)$ and $\left(\frac{1}{n'}, \frac{1}{m'}\right)$.  Use an argument based on Cauchy sequences to conclude that any Cauchy sequence of $S$ (that isn't on the diagonal) will eventually only vary in one of its components.  Find the limit.

It's been a loooong time since I did this problem (10 years?) but that should at least be a big hint.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution: let $$B=\{(\frac1n,0)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{(0,\frac1n)\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{(0,0)\}.$$ Now, note that horizontal and vertical strips of the form $(a,b)\times\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R\times(c,d)$ are open sets. The complement of $B\cup S$ is a union of such strips. Therefore, $B\cup S$ is closed, so it must contain every accumulation point of $S$. To complete the proof, it remains to verify that each point in $S$ is isolated (since we already know that every point in $B$ is an accumulation point).

Comment: I like this solution but I have a little problem. Are you sure that the horizontal and vertical strips are all the complement? I am still trying to convince myself of this with pictures.

Comment: @Dejan:  nice, that's more topological than mine.  I've had random walks on my mind recently. :)

Comment: Ok, after some pictures I am totally convinced that the strips are the complement. Thanks to both of you, now I'll try to solve it with the Cauchy sequences approach.

Comment: @user100106: Note that $B\cup S=K\times K$, where $K=\{\frac1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$. Now, $K\times K = (K\times\mathbb R)\cap(\mathbb R\times K)$. Therefore, $(K\times K)^C=(K\times\mathbb R)^C\cup(\mathbb R\times K)^C$ by De Morgan's law. So, it suffices to prove that $(K\times\mathbb R)^C$ and $(\mathbb R\times K)^C$ are unions of strips, which basically comes down to proving that $\mathbb R\setminus K$ is a union of open intervals.

Comment: @nomen: glad you like it :)